# $A\cup B$ is connected proof

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

> Let $A$ and $B$ be connected subspaces of a topological space $(X,\tau)$. If $A\cap B\neq\emptyset$, prove that the subspace $A\cup B$ is connected.

If the subspace $A\cup B$ is not connected, then there exist, $\mathscr{U},\mathscr{V}\subset X$ such that $\mathscr{U}\cup\mathscr{V}=A\cup B$ and $\mathscr{U}\cap\mathscr{V}=\emptyset$.  $\mathscr{U},\mathscr{V}$ must belong either to $A$ or $B$, like $\mathscr{U}\in A$, which contradicts the fact $A$ and $B$ are connected. Therefore $A\cup B$ is connected.

**Questions**:

Is my proof right? If not. How should I prove the statement?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How $\mathscr{U}, \mathscr{V} \subset A \;\text{or} \;B$ ?

Comment: That $A\cap B\neq\emptyset$ is an important assumption. Your proof has no hope to be true if you make no use of it.

Comment: @ChinnapparajR I did not say subset but $\in$

Comment: @AdditIdent Could you tell me how should I use that assumption?

Comment: No! I does't mean that, Can you explain that line?

Comment: Since $\mathscr{U}\subset A\cup B$, then $\mathscr{U}\in A$ or $\mathscr{U}\in B$. The same would happen to $\mathscr{V}$. This would violate the assumption that boht spaces $A$ and $B$ are connected. That was what I meant on that line.

Comment: Your proof is obviously flawed -- note that you can just take $\mathscr U = A$ and $\mathscr V = B\setminus A$. You've made no further demands on $\mathscr U$ or $\mathscr V$ other than $\mathscr U \cup \mathscr V = A\cup B$ and $\mathscr U \cap \mathscr V = \varnothing$.

Comment: So why $\mathscr{U} \in A$ or $\mathscr{U} \in B$?

Comment: @MPW If I demand $\mathscr{U}$ and $\mathscr{V}$ to be clopen?

Comment: **Hint**: there is some $x$ in both $A$ and $B$. If you have $\mathscr{U}$ and $\mathscr{V}$ disjoint as assumed, $x \in \mathscr{U}$ or $x \in \mathscr{V}$. Then at least one of $\mathscr{U}$ and $\mathscr{V}$ intersects both $A$ and $B$.

Comment: I don't see that in your proof. Why would a reader assume that?

Comment: @MPW Because they are two disjoint open sets whose union is the whole subspace topology.

Comment: Your concepts are really problematic so do things slowly... Think about $[0,1]$ and $[2,3]$ each are connected in real, but their union is not.

Comment: Then $[0,\ 1]$ and $(1,\ 2]$? Each connected and and union is. Indeed if $A$ and $B$ are separated by open sets in ambient space $X$ you can take $\mathscr{U}$, $\mathscr{V}$ as @MPW says.

Comment: I guess you're uncertain about openness in the ambient space and subspace. See $[0,1]$ and $[2,3]$ are closed in real, but each is open too in $[0,1]\cup[2,3]$. We consider connectedness of subspace with respect to clopen sets in subspace topology.

Comment: @AdditIdent            So would it be correct to consider $\mathscr{U}$ and $\mathscr{V}$ open in the subspace topology $A\cup B$?

Comment: Yes. Essentially definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A subspace $Y$ of a topological space is disconnected (w.r.t. subspace
> topology) if there exist two *non-empty open sets $U, V$ in the
> subspace topology of $Y$ such that $U\bigcup V=Y$ and $U\bigcap
>  V=\varnothing$*. A representation of $Y$ as a union of two non-empty sets which are open in subspace topology is called a disconnection.

Here $Y=A\bigcup B$ with $A\bigcap B\not=\phi$ and $A,B$ are connected subspaces of $X$. So if possible, let $Y$ be disconnected w.r.t. subspace topology, then we can find two sets $U, V$ having the properties of 1st paragraph. Now since $A$ is connected, $A $ is contained in one of the open sets, say $U$ (otherwise $A=(A\cap U)\bigcup (A\cap V)$ will be a disconnection of $A$). Similarly, $B$ is also contained in one of the sets $U, V$. Now since $A\bigcap B\not=\varnothing$ we can say $B$ is contained in $U$. Hence $V=\varnothing$. Therefore $A\bigcup B$ is connected.

Comment: The contradiction lies in the fact $V$ cannot be $\emptyset$, since $Y$ is disconnected, right?

Comment: Yes , if you start with the assumption that $Y$ is disconnected.

Answer (score 2):

Call $p$, the point of intersection. Then $p$ lies in either $\mathscr{U}$ or $\mathscr{V}$. Suppose $p\in \mathscr{U}$. Since $A$ and $B$  are connected, it must lie completely in $\mathscr{U}$ or $\mathscr{V}$ and it cannot lie in $\mathscr{V}$, since it contains the point $p$ of $\mathscr{U}$. Consequently $A \cup B \subset \mathscr{U}$, which means $\mathscr{V}=\phi$, a contradiction!

[Here we use the fact that " if $Y$ is a connected subspace of $X=C \cup D$, then $Y \subset C$ or $Y \subset D$ ]